# Two-way binding combobox to enum

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, enumeration

I have a View that is linked to my ViewModel using a DataTemplate, like this

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel}">
    <Views:View />
</DataTemplate>
```

The ViewModel holds a property `ProcessOption` that is of type `MyEnum?`, where `MyEnum` is a custom enumeration that has let's say 3 values: `Single`, `Multiple` and `All`. I am trying to bind a combobox to this property, so the approach I am following is:

ViewModel has a property of `List<string>` that is

```
public List<string> Options
    {
        get 
        {
            return Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)).ToList();
        }
    }
```

to which I bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `Combobox`. Then, in addition to the `ProcessOption` property, the ViewModel also has an `OptionName` property (of `string`), which is intended to hold the selected option's name. The ViewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and both properties raise the `PropertyChanged` event in their setters. The binding I am using then is:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Options}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding OptionName}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding ProcessOption}"/>
```

This works fine up to this point. Initially the combobox is empty and both properties are `null`, and when the user selects an option this is propagated to the ViewModel as it should.

The problem appears when I load the data from a Database, and I want to load the controls with initial values. In this case, in the ViewModel's constructor I have this:

```
this.ProcessOption = objectFromDB.ProcessOption // this is the value restored from DB,        let's say it is MyEnum.Multiple
this.OptionName = Options.First(x => x.Equals(Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum), objectFromDB.ProcessOption)));
```

The problem is, although the above sets the two properties to their correct values, they are later set to null from the `Combobox` binding, so the initial values are not kept. I have also tried to do something like `if (value == null) { return; }` in the properties' setters, in which case they have the correct values after the View loads, however the `Combobox` still does not display the correct option, it is empty.

I should also note that I've also tried setting `IsSynchronisedWithCurrentItem` and it doesn't make any difference, apart from the fact that the first element is displayed instead of the combobox being empty.

Can anyone help with this binding? Any help will be very much appreciated, this is driving me crazy!

Comment: Have you tried to bind only on the SelectedItem or SelectedValue property of the combobox instead of both? I think your problem could be in that direction.

Comment: Wow, that did it. Can't believe I didn't try this, binding only to SelectedItem works, and then I can get the other property from the one that's bound. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Options}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding OptionName}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding ProcessOption}"/>
```

Your binding doesn't look like it should work at all -- you don't have TwoWay binding set up, and I think `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` is an either/or proposition.

I suggest that you get rid of `OptionName` and just bind `SelectedItem` to `ProcessOption` (TwoWay) with an `IValueConverter` that will convert to/from `string`.

Comment: TwoWay works by default in this case I think. However you are right, binding to only one of SelectedItem/SelectedValue works, as also suggested by [Bram W.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/960585/bram-w) in the comment above